# jquery mouse move not working on touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I 've got a mouse move event to scroll a div .But when when tried to access the functionality using a tab it does not work.How can i integrate the functionality onto the touch device.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tim').on('mousemove', function(e) {
         //logic for moving the div
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`touchmove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchmove)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tim').on('touchmove', function(e) {
         //logic for moving the div
    });
});
```